# 403 error when using PHP CURL with a PROXY

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I am trying to build a function that can CURL a URL with a proxy but whatever I try seems to give a 403 error. What else am I missing? Thank you!

Here is my current code:

```
function url_get_contents_proxy ($url) {
$proxy = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:8080';


$proxyauth = 'USER:PASS';

echo $url;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $proxy;
echo "<br><br>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return page 1:yes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); // http request timeout 20 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follow redirects, need this if the url changes
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2); //if http server gives redirection responce
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // cookies storage / here the changes have been made
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // false for https
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // the page encoding

$result = curl_exec($ch); // execute the http request
echo "<br><br>";
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
echo "<br><br>";
curl_close($ch); // close the connection
return $result;
```

}

Exact error returned: The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Without any more detail on what the request is supposed to look like and if you get any additional (log) output on the other end, I'm afraid I can't help much. Try using a network analyzer like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) to see what request is actually sent. Compare this to a successful request, e.g. via your browser or running curl from the CLI.

Comment: Maybe this is an error with the proxy. Can you try another proxy?